# css file is load on localhost 8080 but don't work

Tags: html, css, golang

Данные файла file.css оправляю на клиента в переменной css так:

```
w.Write([]byte(css))
```

В браузере хром вижу, что файл присутствует, но стили не отрабатывает.
При этом страница html отображена и файл javascript работает. Если в закладке Sources хрома в данном файле стилей внести любую коррекцию, например, вставить пробел, - то сразу все стили отрабатывают как надо. Ctr+F5 или file.css?v=10062050 не помогают. Подскажите, плиз, как победить?

Comment: Потому что нужно не только выдавать содержимое, но и [заголовок с типом данных](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26559641/696034)

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, да, Вы правы, - получилось. Спасибо.